# Coq: Proving proposition f (x y) -> f y

Tags: coq, proof

Is it possible to prove

```
Lemma A3 (f x: Prop -> Prop)(y: Prop): f (x y) -> f y.
```

either w/ or (preferably) w/out axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no" to proving w/out axioms (and I'm afraid it may be difficult to find meaningful axioms for proving it either). For suppose

```
Parameter A3: forall (f x:Prop->Prop)(y:Prop), f (x y) -> f y.
Definition f' (x:Prop) := x.
Definition X := fun _:Prop => True.
Check A3 f' X False: True -> False.
```

`A3 f' X False` has type `True -> False`, which is unprovable

Comment: I'd instead say that `A3` is *unprovable* in a consistent logic, otherwise as you have shown we can get a proof of falsehood. `Check (A3 (fun x => x) (fun _ => True) False I) : False.`